IF second char in value is 'X' output should be existing first char + 'X'
need and assistance, please.
Need to create new column.In column Company i have few values like  D 00, DEXI, DX00, DX. I need to make a statement: Everytime when second char in cell is "X" or " " should return me DX, else should return me two first chars like DE(second example). Same situation whith other letters, when I have WX, W 00 and so on.

See text functions at learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/text-functions particularly text.range and text.split   Then use an if...then... statement in a custom column

Im quite new in Power query, basically know text functions , what it particular does but do not know sequence, order of application.

You can also try this
=if Text.Middle([Input],1,1)=" " then Text.Start([Input],1) & "X" else Text.Start([Input],2)



you are welcome. if it works, pls accept the answer as the solution. thanks

Create a table, here Table1, that shows which character you want to look up as the second character and what you want to return if it is found

On another table, bring in your data, and add column .. custom column ...
let  a=Text.Range([Column1],1,1), b= List.PositionOf(Table1[SecondCharacter],a), c= if b<0 then Text.Start([Column1],2) else Table1[Show]{b} in c

being sure to replace Column1 with the name of the column you are actually looking up in the input table

Paste this code into the Advanced Editor.
Change the table name in the Source line as needed.
let

//change next line to reflect actual table name
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table6"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Input", type text}}),
    
    
    #"First Two" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type","Output",(r)=>
        let 
            split = Text.ToList(r[Input]),
            secondCharacter= if split{1}=" " then "X" else split{1}
        in split{0} & secondCharacter, type text)
in
    #"First Two"


